# I m not able to login to my worpress site after i installed wpbakery addon plugin. i get the following fatal error

Tags: wordpress

Fatal error: Call to undefined function vc_map_integrate_shortcode() in /home/ritgoaac/public_html/wp-content/plugins/addons-for-visual-composer/includes/addons/testimonials-slider/cla

Comment: Your question looks quite chaotic, would you please edit it? See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact your hosting provider OR login via ftp and remove the plugin inside `wp-content/plugins/`